# interceptor in AndroidNetworking

Tags: android, interceptor

I have a use case in my android app in which every response except one that i receive from server is encrypted so i was trying to call the decryption method on android side in the  AndroidNetworking interceptor and then send the decrypted value ahead.
Also in the first scenario that is on login i get access token which isnt encrypted and which should not be intercepted and decrypted while everything else should.
please suggest me the best method for this as i am new to android and rxJava.

Answer (score 0):

For networking, you should probably look into [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).
It has support for interceptors as it internally uses OkHTTP.

If you are new to Android, you should probably stay away from Rx as the learning curve would too steep.